# Time evolution coefficients of harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, time-evolution

I want to calculate the function 
$$\varphi(x,0) = \frac15(3 \Psi_0 + 4 \Psi_1)$$
for a later point in time. I know the formula for the time evolution is $$\Psi(x,t)=\sum_{n=0}^N c_n \Psi_n e^{-i \frac{E_n}{\hbar} t}.$$

How do I calculate the evolution coefficients? In my case $c_n$ seems to be one but why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $t=0$ to get on the one hand
$$
\Psi(x,0)=\sum_n c_n \Psi_n
$$
and compare with $\varphi(x,0)= \frac{3}{5}\Psi_0 +\frac{4}{5}\Psi_1$.  Alternatively, set $t=0$ and use orthogonality of the wavefunctions to find
$$
c_n=\int dx\, \varphi(x,0)\,\Psi^*_n(x)\, .
$$